# Using a GUI to write to a CSV file cells

Tags: python, database, csv, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make a GUI that will write to a CSV file. I want whatever I put into the entry boxes to write to a corresponding cell.

An example of entries I want to see in the CSV is:

```
vlan 8
192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
fa2/0/1
```

however, when I open the `data1.csv` it writes:

```
PY_VAR0
PY_VAR1
PY_VAR2
```

Here is the python code I wrote:

```
import csv
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
root.title("Cisco-Oneport")
photo = PhotoImage(file = "Logo.PNG")
root.iconphoto(False, photo)

def info():
    list_of_lists = [[f'{vlan}',],
                    [f'{ip}',],
                    [f'{port}',]]

    with open('data1.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
        for sublist in list_of_lists:
            writer.writerow(sublist)

entry1_text = Label(text = "Type Vlan Number * ",)
entry2_text = Label(text = "Type IP Number and Subnet * ",)
entry3_text = Label(text = "Type in Fast Port * ",)

entry1_text.place(x = 15, y = 30)
entry2_text.place(x = 15, y = 90)
entry3_text.place(x = 15, y = 150)

vlan = StringVar()
ip = StringVar()
port = StringVar()

vlan_entry = Entry(textvariable = vlan, width = "10")
ip_entry = Entry(textvariable = ip, width = "30")
port_entry = Entry(textvariable = port, width = "10")

vlan_entry.place(x = 15, y = 60)
ip_entry.place(x = 15, y = 120)
port_entry.place(x = 15, y = 180)


register = Button(root,text = "Run", width = "10", height = "2", command = info, bg = "lightgreen")
register.place(x = 15, y = 240)

root.mainloop()
```

How do I get the desired inputs? I'm pretty new to light GUI coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .csv file is showing the tcl/tk names for the `StringVars`.  Use `.get()` to get the values.  The Labels and Entries were created without a containing object so I was seeing one GUI with the Text and a separate one with the run button.

It's easier to answer questions where the code can be copied and run in a console. Therefore it's better to remove things like icons which use files that won't exist on another PC.

```
import csv
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
root.title("Cisco-Oneport")

# Removed icon as I cant access the file

# Use .get() to get the values of the StringVars, not the names of the StringVars
def info():
    list_of_lists = [[f'{vlan.get()}',],
                    [f'{ip.get()}',],
                    [f'{port.get()}',]]

    with open('data1.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
        for sublist in list_of_lists:
            writer.writerow(sublist)

# Add root to put the all the objects in the same GUI
entry1_text = Label(root, text = "Type Vlan Number * ",)
entry2_text = Label(root, text = "Type IP Number and Subnet * ",)
entry3_text = Label(root, text = "Type in Fast Port * ",)

entry1_text.place(x = 15, y = 30)
entry2_text.place(x = 15, y = 90)
entry3_text.place(x = 15, y = 150)

vlan = StringVar()
ip = StringVar()
port = StringVar()

# Add root to put the all the objects in the same GUI
vlan_entry = Entry(root, textvariable = vlan, width = "10")
ip_entry = Entry(root, textvariable = ip, width = "30")
port_entry = Entry(root, textvariable = port, width = "10")

vlan_entry.place(x = 15, y = 60)
ip_entry.place(x = 15, y = 120)
port_entry.place(x = 15, y = 180)

# 
register = Button(root,text = "Run", width = "10", height = "2", command = info, bg = "lightgreen")
register.place(x = 15, y = 240)

root.mainloop()
```